# select link mutiple class in table body in find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

There is a table like below
I would like to select element with `'nav test-step-actions'` class.

there are multiple data but other id and things can't be used due to it happen to changed

so I tried to make tr separately but I can't find solution.
the code that I tried:

```
self.gearbu= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='project-config-versions-add']/tr[0]/td[class='nav test-step-actions']")
self.gearbu= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='zephyr-restfultable-tbody']/tr[0]/td[6]")

<form id="project-config-versions-add" class="aui" action="#">
                <table id="project-config-steps-table" class="aui jira-restfultable jira-restfultable-allowhover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="jira-restfultable-order"><!-- order --></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Test Step</th>
                            <th>Test Data</th>
                            <th>Expected Result</th>
                            <th><!-- Operations --></th>
                            <!--<th style="width:100px;"> throbber </th>-->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                <tbody id="zephyr-restfultable-tbody" class="ui-sortable"><tr classname="project-config-version" id="step-126-row" data-id="126" class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-readonly"><td class="jira-restfultable-order"><span class="jira-restfultable-draghandle"></span></td><td class="project-config-version-name zteststep-order"><span data-field-name="orderId" class="zfj-nowrap">1</span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-step"><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="step"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>a</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-data "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="data"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>b</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-result "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="result"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>c</p></span></td><!--<td class="project-config-operations" style="width:50px;">c</td>--><td class="nav test-step-actions"><a href="teststep-dd-126" aria-owns="teststep-dd-126" aria-haspopup="true" class="aui-steps-dropdown aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-style-default aui-dd-link icon-tools-small" style="visibility: hidden;" data-clicked="0" aria-controls="teststep-dd-126"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small"></span></a><!-- .aui-dropdown2 --><div id="teststep-dd-126" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default" data-dropdown2-alignment="left" aria-hidden="true" style="left: 1171px; top: 698px; display: none;"><ul class="aui-list-truncate"><li><a href="#" id="step-126-action-clone" class="test-step-action-clone" style="visibility: visible;" data-clicked="0">Clone</a></li><li><a id="step-126-operations-trigger" class="project-config-operations-trigger" href="#" style="visibility: visible;" data-clicked="0">Delete</a></li></ul></div></td><!--<td class="project-config-throbber"></td>--></tr><tr classname="project-config-version" id="step-127-row" data-id="127" class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-readonly"><td class="jira-restfultable-order"><span class="jira-restfultable-draghandle"></span></td><td class="project-config-version-name zteststep-order"><span data-field-name="orderId" class="zfj-nowrap">2</span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-step"><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="step"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>d</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-data "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="data"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>a</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-result "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="result"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>d</p></span></td><!--<td class="project-config-operations" style="width:50px;">c</td>--><td class="nav test-step-actions"><a href="teststep-dd-127" aria-owns="teststep-dd-127" aria-haspopup="true" class="aui-steps-dropdown aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-style-default aui-dd-link icon-tools-small" style="visibility: hidden;" aria-controls="teststep-dd-127" data-clicked="0"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small"></span></a><!-- .aui-dropdown2 --><div id="teststep-dd-127" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default" data-dropdown2-alignment="left" aria-hidden="true" style="left: 695px; top: 788px; display: none;"><ul class="aui-list-truncate"><li><a href="#" id="step-127-action-clone" class="test-step-action-clone" style="visibility: visible;" data-clicked="0">Clone</a></li><li><a id="step-127-operations-trigger" class="project-config-operations-trigger" href="#" style="visibility: visible;" data-clicked="0">Delete</a></li></ul></div></td><!--<td class="project-config-throbber"></td>--></tr><tr classname="project-config-version" id="step-128-row" data-id="128" class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-readonly"><td class="jira-restfultable-order"><span class="jira-restfultable-draghandle"></span></td><td class="project-config-version-name zteststep-order"><span data-field-name="orderId" class="zfj-nowrap">3</span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-step"><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="step"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>h</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-data "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="data"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>g</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-result "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="result"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>d</p></span></td><!--<td class="project-config-operations" style="width:50px;">c</td>--><td class="nav test-step-actions"><a href="teststep-dd-128" aria-owns="teststep-dd-128" aria-haspopup="true" class="aui-steps-dropdown aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-style-default aui-dd-link icon-tools-small" style="visibility: hidden;" aria-controls="teststep-dd-128" data-clicked="0"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small"></span></a><!-- .aui-dropdown2 --><div id="teststep-dd-128" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default" data-dropdown2-alignment="left" aria-hidden="true" style="left: 695px; top: 838px; display: none;"><ul class="aui-list-truncate"><li><a href="#" id="step-128-action-clone" class="test-step-action-clone" style="visibility: visible;">Clone</a></li><li><a id="step-128-operations-trigger" class="project-config-operations-trigger" href="#" style="visibility: visible;">Delete</a></li></ul></div></td><!--<td class="project-config-throbber"></td>--></tr><tr classname="project-config-version" id="step-129-row" data-id="129" class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-readonly"><td class="jira-restfultable-order"><span class="jira-restfultable-draghandle"></span></td><td class="project-config-version-name zteststep-order"><span data-field-name="orderId" class="zfj-nowrap">4</span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-step"><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="step"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>a</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-data "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="data"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>b</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-result "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="result"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>c</p></span></td><!--<td class="project-config-operations" style="width:50px;">c</td>--><td class="nav test-step-actions"><a href="teststep-dd-129" aria-owns="teststep-dd-129" aria-haspopup="true" class="aui-steps-dropdown aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-style-default aui-dd-link icon-tools-small" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small"></span></a><div id="teststep-dd-129" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default"><ul class="aui-list-truncate"><li><a href="#" id="step-129-action-clone" class="test-step-action-clone" style="visibility: visible;">Clone</a></li><li><a id="step-129-operations-trigger" class="project-config-operations-trigger" href="#" style="visibility: visible;">Delete</a></li></ul></div><!-- .aui-dropdown2 --></td><!--<td class="project-config-throbber"></td>--></tr><tr classname="project-config-version" id="step-130-row" data-id="130" class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-readonly"><td class="jira-restfultable-order"><span class="jira-restfultable-draghandle"></span></td><td class="project-config-version-name zteststep-order"><span data-field-name="orderId" class="zfj-nowrap">5</span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-step"><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="step"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>a</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-data "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="data"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>b</p></span></td><td class="project-config-version-description zteststep-result "><span class="jira-restfultable-editable zfj-editable-field" data-field-name="result"><span class="icon icon-edit-sml zfj-overlay-icon"></span><p>c</p></span></td><!--<td class="project-config-operations" style="width:50px;">c</td>--><td class="nav test-step-actions"><a href="teststep-dd-130" aria-owns="teststep-dd-130" aria-haspopup="true" class="aui-steps-dropdown aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-style-default aui-dd-link icon-tools-small" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small"></span></a><div id="teststep-dd-130" class="aui-dropdown2 aui-style-default"><ul class="aui-list-truncate"><li><a href="#" id="step-130-action-clone" class="test-step-action-clone" style="visibility: visible;">Clone</a></li><li><a id="step-130-operations-trigger" class="project-config-operations-trigger" href="#" style="visibility: visible;">Delete</a></li></ul></div><!-- .aui-dropdown2 --></td><!--<td class="project-config-throbber"></td>--></tr></tbody><tbody class="jira-restfultable-create"><tr class="jira-restfultable-row jira-restfultable-editrow jira-restfultable-focused"><td class="jira-restfultable-order"><span class="jira-restfultable-draghandle"></span></td><td></td><td class="teststep-editable teststep-editable-step"><textarea name="step" rows="4" class="ztextarea noresize ztextarea-step"></textarea>  <div class="wiki-preview-content"></div><div class="wiki-field-tools"><a class="zephyr-wiki-preview_link fullscreen" tabindex="-1" href="#" id="zephyr-wiki-preview_link" title="preview"><span class="aui-icon wiki-renderer-icon"></span></a><a class="help-link" id="viewHelp" tabindex="-1" href="/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all" title="Get local help about wiki markup help" data-helplink="local"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span></a></div></td><td class="teststep-editable teststep-editable-data"><textarea name="data" rows="4" class="ztextarea noresize ztextarea-data"></textarea>  <div class="wiki-preview-content"></div><div class="wiki-field-tools"><a class="zephyr-wiki-preview_link fullscreen" tabindex="-1" href="#" id="zephyr-wiki-preview_link" title="preview"><span class="aui-icon wiki-renderer-icon"></span></a><a class="help-link" id="viewHelp" tabindex="-1" href="/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all" title="Get local help about wiki markup help" data-helplink="local"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span></a></div></td><td class="teststep-editable teststep-editable-result"><textarea name="result" rows="4" class="ztextarea noresize ztextarea-result"></textarea>    <div class="wiki-preview-content"></div><div class="wiki-field-tools"><a class="zephyr-wiki-preview_link fullscreen" tabindex="-1" href="#" id="zephyr-wiki-preview_link" title="preview"><span class="aui-icon wiki-renderer-icon"></span></a><a class="help-link" id="viewHelp" tabindex="-1" href="/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all" title="Get local help about wiki markup help" data-helplink="local"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-help"></span></a></div></td><!-- Original code --><!--<td class="jira-restfultable-icon project-config-release-status"><span class="project-config-icon project-config-icon-version"></span></td><td class="project-config-version-name"><input name="name" type="text" class="text" value=""  /><input name="project" type="hidden" value="undefined"></td><td class="project-config-version-description"><input name="description" type="text" class="text" value=""  /></td><td class="project-config-version-release-date"><div class="project-config-date-field"><input id="project-config-version-release-date-field" name="userReleaseDate" type="text" class="text short-field" value="" /><a href="#" id="project-config-versions-release-date-trigger" title="Select a date"><span class="aui-icon icon-date">Select a date</span></a></div></td>--><td class="jira-restfultable-operations"><div class="restfultable-operations-wrapper"><input class="aui-button" type="submit" value="Add"></div></td><td class="jira-restfultable-throbber"></td></tr></tbody></table>
            </form>
```

How can I find element by xpath in selenium?

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but it still quite unclear. Can you clarify what is your current and desired output? Share the exception if you got any

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd xpath is wrong because in xpath numeration starts with 1 (not 0). Correct version is:

```
//tbody[@id='zephyr-restfultable-tbody']/tr[1]/td[6]
```

Your first xpath is wrong because of: a)numeration mistake; b) a <tr> is not a direct child of the form (single slash instead of double); c) a name of attribute in xpath must start wich '@'. More correct version is:

```
//form[@id='project-config-versions-add']//tbody[@id='zephyr-restfultable-tbody']/tr[1]/td[@class='nav test-step-actions']
```

Or the chorter one:

```
//form[@id='project-config-versions-add']//tr[1]/td[@class='nav test-step-actions']
```